# Does pairing children with their parents cause any harm (in a genetic program)?

Tags: reference-request, genetic-algorithms, fitness-functions, genetic-programming, crossover-operators

If you pair parents with their children (with a cross-over) does this prevent making individuals which are more fit or does this cause other side effects which are harmful to the genetic process?

I can provide any specifics about my concrete program but don't know what is relevant (and cannot write the whole setup here).

**EDIT:** As I think I figured out the answer myself I'll add the information that I think is relevant,

if I'm wrong, and you'd need more information, don't hesitate to ask (I check stack exchange quite often and am always pleased to communicate).

The relevant information:

2 parents create 2 children with a random 10-point cross-over.

The 10 points get chosen out of 700 lines of dna.

(See my answer for more information.)

Comment: I assume that, in your case, children are derived from parents by applying a mutation to the parents. Right?

Comment: You're asking or raising at least 2-3 distinct questions or problems, respectively, here. First, you seem to be asking if pairing a child with a parent can prevent diversity. Second, the question in the title. Third, whether combining the child and the parent can lead to fitter individuals. I assume that the question in the title is your main question and the others are just follow-up or sub questions, but I recommend that you edit your post to either leave only one question or clarify which of the questions is your main one. This would help answerers to focus on one question.

Comment: By the way, if you're looking for research on any topic, you can use the tag [tag:reference-request]. This will clarify that you're not looking for a debate.

Comment: Please, also change the title accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Children pairing with their parents has a chance of harming the genetic process:

If a child pairs with one of it's parents it's possible to have identical fit individuals who pair with each other (and produce identical individuals, so stalling the genetic process).

This chance is still existing, but diminishes drastically if children are not allowed to be paired with their parents (but still with their grandparents).

In that case a grandchild has dna of 4 different individuals, so it's still possible to have a cross-over which is identical to itself, but chances are very slim and are very unlikely to harm the genetic process.